# SpeechRecognizer.startListening not working on Chromebook 10 but works on Pixel 2XL

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, voice-recognition, chromebook

I have voice recognition code that crashes upon launch (after the splashscreen). My app works great without voice recognition, but it is required for this app that I have it.

This Acer Chromebook 10 outside of my development has no issue with voice recognition (Okay Google, what time is it... etc.)
Here is a partial screenshot of the error I am getting from logcat on the Chromebook:

[image]

I have added permissions in the manifest (before I added this it worked on the Pixel 2XL):

```
<addPermission android:name="android.permission.BIND_VOICE_INTERACTION"/>
```

... but still get the same error. I am not launching a competing service, but rather a thread runnable activity. Here is a snippet of the code that I think that may be throwing this error (it crashes right after the splash screen so I don't even get the catch response):

```
  try
  {
    _activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
    public void run()
        {
        // I don't know why, but we have to destroy and redo the recognizer after a failure (unlike onResult), then works great.
        mSpeechRecognizer.destroy(); 
        mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(recognitionListener);

        mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");

        mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
        }
    });
  } // end of try
  catch (Exception e)
    {
    Log.debug("Recognition failed with exception " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Some background - like the title says this code is working with Pixel 2XL. It is part of an in-house plugin that I've written for the Unreal Engine to support voice recognition. As such I test for the permission "android.permission.BIND_VOICE_INTERACTION" in Blueprints (a flowchart-like language for UE4) when running the code on my Pixel and it comes back true - so I know this permission is okay with the Pixel 2XL.
I get the impression that there may be a competing service causing conflict on the Chromebook specifically (ArcVoiceInteractionService?) and if this is so, I need to find out how to get around it.

Comment: This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64331678/2240880

Comment: @VIH Thank you- I'll try that when I get a chance!