# SpeechRecognizer not available when targeting Android 11

Tags: android, android-11, android-speech-api

While testing an application after increasing the targetLevel to 30, I found that the [SpeechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer) is not available any more, i.e. `SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable()`
always return false.

If I set the targetLevel back to 29, without changing anything else, it is available again. This happens on a real device (Pixel 3a) and the emulator.

It doesn't seem to be a [behaviour change](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11). The only requirement mentioned by the Recognizer API is the `Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO`

I also found no clue in the logcat.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

Trying to actually use the (allegedly not available) recognizer lead to this message in the logcat :

```
10-13 09:19:50.273  1531  1799 I AppsFilter: interaction: PackageSetting{eb6a1b2 my.application.package/10225} -> PackageSetting{ab34503 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/10140} BLOCKED
10-13 09:19:50.273  1531  1799 W ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=android.speech.RecognitionService cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.voicesearch.serviceapi.GoogleRecognitionService } U=0: not found
10-13 09:19:50.273 25348 25348 E SpeechRecognizer: bind to recognition service failed
```

So the problem seems to be related to this [new Android 11 "feature"](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility), and the solution was to add a query to the manifest for the blocked intent :

```
<manifest ...>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

Comment: Wow, nice find.

Comment: hello, can you check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65476014/error-insufficient-permissions-with-android-11

Comment: wow, really did not expect this. thank you mah man!

Comment: Great find man, exact solution to the problem. +1

Comment: adding intent causes another issue to come up of ":app:processDebugMainManifest". with out adding the intent tag the app runs but Speech Recognition does not work

Comment: Seems like there is a new bug on Android 13. I just updated my Android version and now it doesn't work.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-all#speech-service

Comment: They actually removed the Voice Recognition service.  "Android 13 removes the SpeechService implementation"

Comment: If I understand correctly, they did not remove the API, they moved the implementation from one app (Google app) to another (Speech Services by Google). This should not be a problem unless the application hard-codes somehow the speech service implementation's provider.
Anyway my app still work on Android 13 without any changes in the code using the recognizer, even after increasing the target SDK to API 33