# Speech Recognition for Android Wear-OS App

Tags: android, kotlin, speech-recognition, wear-os, speech-to-text

I've built a voice-driven android app that uses the android speech recognition API. I'm currently trying to convert the app to a wear-os version. I've included the speech recognition permission in the apps manifest and have initialized the speech recognition instance the same as I have in the mobile app (which works!). The app launches well, however when I begin the speech recognition I get the following error:
E/SpeechRecognizer: no selected voice recognition service

I've tested on both a physical Galaxy 5 watch, and an API 30 wear-os emulator and the problem occurs with both devices. I've installed google assistant on the devices, and google assistants voice recognition works well. I can't find and voice input / speech recognition settings on the app.
I'm not sure what next steps to take in debugging this.

Comment: Did you [add visibility to all `RecognitionService` instances](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11#speech-recognition)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I've included a RecognitionService action in the queries part of the manifest, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @Rice have you resolved this?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me when using speech recognition on Android 11 in Wear OS:

```
   private fun checkPermissions() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != 
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO),
                REQUEST_MICROPHONE_PERMISSION
            )
        }
    }

   @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, 
     data: Intent?) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT && resultCode == 
    Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        val results = 
       data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS)
        val spokenText = results?.firstOrNull()

        spokenText?.let {
            sendRequest(it)
        }
    }
}

   @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n", "InflateParams")
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        checkPermissions()
    }


  val voiceButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.voiceButton)

    voiceButton.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)

        // on below line we are passing language model
        // and model free form in our intent
        intent.putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM
        )

        // on below line we are passing our
        // language as a default language.
        intent.putExtra(
         RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US"
        )

        // on below line we are specifying a prompt
        // message as speak to text on below line.
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak to 
        text")


        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 
            REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // on below line we are displaying error message in 
            toast
            Toast
                .makeText(
                    this@MainActivity, " " + e.message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                )
                .show()
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Changes to SpeechRecognition in API Level 30**

I have the same problem: Testing it on an android 30 emulator prints "no selected voice recognition service". However, testing it on an emulator running API version 28 works just fine.

I asked for user permission and specified an intent in the "queries"-Part of AndroidManifest.xml it still doesnt work. It seems to be an API Problem.

[This answer helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64319117/speechrecognizer-not-available-when-targeting-android-11/64331678#64331678)

Comment: did you find solution for this? I have the same issue

Comment: Sadly, I gave up at this point. Sorry :(