# Is speech recognition is available on Galaxy Watch 4?

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os, voice-recognition, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

I try to make a voice recognition on my Galaxy Watch 4 in Kotlin language with Android Studio and it seems that it is not available on this device.

The value of SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this) is False.

I have put the permission:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`

I tried to add this:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

But the value of SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this) is still False.

Is it possible to use voice recognition with coding or is it impossible on a Galaxy Watch 4?
I read that WearOS 3 can't make voice recognition with coding. Is it true?

Comment: Just making sure you've seen: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/user-input/voice#GetSpeechInput

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76293037/speech-recognition-for-android-wear-os-app

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately, Wear OS 3 (which the Galaxy Watch 4 runs on) **does not** support direct native speech recognition.